# What is better to use out-of-the-box Audit Trail or custom?

Tags: siebel, audit-trail

What can you recommend to me out-of-the-box Audit Trail or custom? 
What are advantages and disadvantages of implementation of each of them?

Answer (score 0):

Siebel practioniers always advice using Out-of-box functionality wherever possible, thats the essence of using a packaged application. From Siebel 8 onwards, Siebel can audit any business component's any table/column. All it needs is to turn it on in the Adminitration->Audit Trail screens. It can even track deleted records from the system, and even read instances (who all have seen the field value).

It will be too complex to implement a custom audit trail feature which could be better than this one.